# groupby in descending order in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by

I am not getting my desired output when using group by and order by in laravel
here is my code

```
 $old=DB::table('tbl1')
      ->leftJoin('tbl2','tbl1.id','=','tbl2.tbl1_id')
      ->whereDate('tbl2.created_at','<' ,Carbon::today())
      ->where('tbl1.users_id',$id)
      ->select('tbl2.name as name','tbl1.teacher as teacher','table2.class_id as class_id')
      ->orderBy('tbl2.created_at','desc')
      ->groupBy('tbl2.class_id')
      ->get()
      ->toArray();
```

group by working fine but it not returning me the latest value i just want to get latest value of class_id based on create time

Comment: Edit in `config/database.php`. In `mysql` array , set to `strict => false`

Comment: you didn't understand my question . actually I am getting results based on groupby() but not getting the latest one

Comment: Would you need to make a subquery?

Comment: @RoëlGonzalez can you elaborate ,how I create subquery in that case?

Comment: Can you run `->toSql` instead of `->get()` and show what the resulting query is?

Answer (score 0):

Use **first()** instead of **get()**. It will only take first row which is the latest value. I assume the rest of your query is correct

```
$old=DB::table('tbl1')
      ->leftJoin('tbl2','tbl1.id','=','tbl2.tbl1_id')
      ->whereDate('tbl2.created_at','<' ,Carbon::today())
      ->where('tbl1.users_id',$id)
      ->select('tbl2.name as name','tbl1.teacher as teacher','table2.class_id as class_id')
      ->orderBy('tbl2.created_at','desc')
      ->groupBy('tbl2.class_id')
      ->first()
      ->toArray();
```

Comment: first return me only one row but I need multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Can you try Group By , then order by.